# Android signed apk key

Tags: android, android-activity, android-keystore

I am using android studio. The first time I generated signed apk, I went to `build-> generate signed apk`.
I created a Key Store at certain path with evry details(password, alias name,validity etc).

Every time I generate signed apk using this key. I select `Release` from the drop-down saying Build Type.

The apk gets generated and uploaded successfully.

I had to generate release key-hash, so I used the same keystore file that I generated from the `build->generate signed apk` menu. Will the key-hash generated be correct one?

ps: my keystore file doesn't have a `.Keystore` extension but it works

Comment: For what do you need the key-hash?

Comment: @PrerakSola for facebook.. The key i generated and the key it is showing in error are different

Comment: If you use the same keystore, you will have the correct one!

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung Ok.. I wanted to make sure that if I create a keystore from "generate signed apk" in "build" menu, that is the correct process to generate a release key

Comment: Remember that you need to keep the generated key forever if you want to update your app in the future. You will need to reuse the key. See more http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html